# Change style on parent mouseover

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I've made a trigger for a viewbox that when the mouse is over the viewbox, the content changes.

This works, but because the content of the viewbox is small I want to have a border around the viewbox that also triggers the mouseover event.

```
<Viewbox Width="50" x:Name="ActionIconBox1" Height="40.5">
    <ContentControl>
        <ContentControl.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                    <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message}"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Viewbox,AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message_focus}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </ContentControl.Style>
    </ContentControl>
</Viewbox>
```

This only works when the mouse is on the contentcontrol, not when the mouse enters the Viewbox.

The resource is a canvas

```
<Canvas xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" x:Name="appbar_message" Width="76" Height="76" Clip="F1 M 0,0L 76,0L 76,76L 0,76L 0,0">
<Path Width="38" Height="39.75" Canvas.Left="19" Canvas.Top="22" Stretch="Fill" Fill="#FF1BA1E2" Data="F1 M 33,51L 36.4167,61.75L 24,51L 19,51L 19,22L 57,22L 57,51L 33,51 Z "/> </Canvas>
```

Why doesn't the binding work?

Comment: What exactly 'doesn't work'? Also, are you trying to link to the `appbar_message` `Canvas` from the `Trigger`? You might have a problem there since you called it `action_message` in the `Trigger`.

Comment: The content only changes when the mouse is on the contentcontrol, the image itself. But not when the mouse is on the viewbox.
Yeah, don't worry about that just a copy paste error. In my code the link is correct.

Comment: do you have margin between viewbox and contentcontrol?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just put it into a border and change the AncestorType.

```
    <Viewbox Width="50" x:Name="ActionIconBox1" Height="40.5" >
        <Border BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Red">
            <ContentControl>
                <ContentControl.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="{x:Type ContentControl}">
                        <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message}"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Border,AncestorLevel=1}, Path=IsMouseOver}" Value="True" >
                                <Setter Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource action_message_focus}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </ContentControl.Style>
            </ContentControl>
        </Border>
    </Viewbox>
```

Answer (score 1):

You put the `Trigger` on the `ContentControl` so of course it only works on that. Just set the size of the `ContentControl` to the same size as the `ViewBox` to remove 'the border' as you call it.